# AWS Data Pipeline RedshiftCopy activity cannot find suitable drivers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I've set up a RedshiftCopy activity in AWS Data Pipeline, but it keeps failing with the following error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for <REDACTED> at private.com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Unknown Source) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:145) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getRedshiftDatabaseConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:80) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:47) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnectionWithCredentials(ConnectionFactory.java:230) at amazonaws.datapipeline.redshift.RedshiftActivityRunnerFactory$RedshiftActivityRunner.<init>(RedshiftActivityRunnerFactory.java:29) at amazonaws.datapipeline.redshift.RedshiftActivityRunnerFactory.create(RedshiftActivityRunnerFactory.java:48) at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.RedshiftCopyActivity.runActivity(RedshiftCopyActivity.java:49) at amazona`
..etc

The "runsOn" EC2 instance is a Data Pipeline-managed resource, so I'm confused by the error, because I assumed that any instance that gets spun up by Data Pipeline, will have all the necessary resources installed.

Has anyone encountered this error before? What, if anything, did you do to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, this is a known issue with AWS Data Pipeline. The suggested workaround for now is to use the Postgres JDBC driver instead of the Redshift one.

(Just change the "`jdbc://redshift...`" in the pipeline configuration to "`jdbc://postgresql...`" keeping everything else the same.)

Comment: if i give postgresql://...  in myRedshiftJdbcConnectStr, then I get the error as :

No suitable driver found for postgresql://...

Am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: No, this used to work when I wrote this answer, but now Data Pipeline is broken again.